# Zero Replacement for missing values in JSON file for Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The JSON will look like as given below.

```
{
"ThresholdTime": "48min", 
"FallTime": "Min", 
"description": "PowerAmplifier"
}
{
"ThresholdTime": "min", 
"FallTime": "200min", 
"description": "DolbyDigitall"
}
```

I am using `regexp_extract` to remove alpha character from alphanumeric string.

```
df.withColumn("NewThresholdTime",regexp_extract("ThresholdTime","(\\d+)",1))
```

How can I add 0 where there is no time for `ThresholdTime` or `FallTime`?

Output should be:

```
+--------+-------------+--------------+----------------+    
|FallTime|ThresholdTime|   NewFallTime|NewThresholdTime|    
+--------+-------------+--------------+----------------+    
|   Min  |        48min|0             |          48    |
|  200min|          min|200           |          0     |    
+--------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: in scala we use when clause.. similar will be available in pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have a dataframe with the values provided in the JSON then, you can check if without numerals the column remains the same then keep as-is, else remove alphabets.

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [{"ThresholdTime": "48min", 
      "FallTime": "15Min", 
      "description": "PowerAmplifier"
    },
    {"ThresholdTime": "min", 
     "FallTime": "200min", 
     "description": "DolbyDigitall"}])

# What would column look like without alhpabets
col_without_alphabets = F.regexp_replace(df["ThresholdTime"], "[a-zA-Z]", "")

# What would column look like without numerals
col_without_numerals = F.regexp_replace(df["ThresholdTime"], "[0-9]", "")

# If without numerals the column remains the same then keep as-is, else remove alphabets
df.withColumn("NewThresholdTime",
              F.when(col_without_numerals == df["ThresholdTime"], 
                     F.lit(0))
              .otherwise(col_without_alphabets)).show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
|FallTime|ThresholdTime|   description|NewThresholdTime|
+--------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
|   15Min|        48min|PowerAmplifier|              48|
|  200min|          min| DolbyDigitall|               0|
+--------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
```

### Adding answer to extend the same for any number of variables.

Loop through whatever variables you would like to do the same for.

```py
new_columns = list()
for column in ["ThresholdTime", "FallTime"]:

    # What would column look like without alphabets
    col_without_alphabets = F.regexp_replace(df[column], "[a-zA-Z]", "")

    # What would column look like without numerals
    col_without_numerals = F.regexp_replace(df[column], "[0-9]", "")

    # If without numerals the column remains the same then keep as-is, else remove alphabets
    new_columns.append(F.when(col_without_numerals == df[column], 
                        F.lit(0)).otherwise(col_without_alphabets).alias("New{}".format(column)))

df.select(["*"] + new_columns).show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+
|FallTime|ThresholdTime|   description|NewThresholdTime|NewFallTime|
+--------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+
|   15Min|        48min|PowerAmplifier|              48|         15|
|  200min|          min| DolbyDigitall|               0|        200|
+--------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sunny...... but what i am looking is to remove character and retain only integer in newFallTime and NewThresholdTime

Comment: Ah, apologies have made a slight edit and it should work now. Please accept the answer if it is what you needed.

Comment: Getting Error as "NameError: name 'F' is not defind. please help

Comment: ``import pyspark.sql.functions as F``

Comment: `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`

Comment: @SunnyShukla: Thanks a ton... can we also do same for falltime when there is no integer in it. Please guide.

Comment: @SunnyShukla: can we do similar way for Falltime ?

Comment: Updated the answer - loop through for any variable you would like too, hope that helps!.